# QGIS doesn't handle PostGis connection resets?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I'm highly frustrated by the fact that if I leave the database alone for a more than a few minutes, I can no longer insert new lines. If I restart QGIS, everything goes back to normal. I believe this is caused by the tcp connection being closed (same problem that causes crashes in PgAdmin)?

Any way to mend that from QGIS side? Or do I have to increase timeouts somehow?

Will pgbouncer help here?

```
2016-10-05T18:15:38 1   NOTICE: WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
2016-10-05T18:37:39 1   Query: BEGIN returned 7 [no result buffer]
2016-10-05T18:37:39 1   resetting bad connection.
2016-10-05T18:37:39 1   retry after reset succeeded.
2016-10-05T18:37:39 1   Query failed: SELECT nextval('features_tal_id_seq'::regclass)
            Error: no result buffer
```

Comment: It's really annoying and still ongoing in 2019