# postgis connection timeout in qgis

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, network

When I connect to my postgis database and edit/add features and keep the edit mode open, many times it loses the connection.

I cannot save my new/edited features and I need to restart the software and start from the beginning. I tried many type of qgis versions and only the 2.12 qgis lyon able to reconnect by clicking on the elephant head and connect and after that I can save the database. With the other versions I just save after every feature and hope it will save the next one as well. Is there any qgis settings or database settings which allows the connection to keep open? We are using qgis on multiple computers and all of them have the same problem... this question is relating to this one but no solution:  [QGIS doesn't handle PostGis connection resets?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213153/qgis-doesnt-handle-postgis-connection-resets)

this is the error generated: [image]

Comment: Hey, can you provide more information. Which versions of QGIS did you try? What happens when you try to save (is there any specific error message)? Did you open a bug report?

Comment: Hi, we are using different versions like: 2.4, 2.6, 2.12 (lyon), 2.14, 2.16. I can confirm that we are stopped using Nodebo and Essen because of this problem, and went back to lyon because there at least we are able to reconnect. I asked my team to send print screen about the error. I will update it later, but as I remember it is just a generic error message.